# Azure Functions - PowerShell - "The pwsh executable cannot be found at ..."

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

When my PowerShell Azure Function runs using the Test/Run feature in the portal, I get this error in the connected console output.

> The pwsh executable cannot be found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.3.1\workers\powershell\7\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp3.1\pwsh.exe"

> Note that 'Start-Job' is not supported by design in scenarios where PowerShell is being hosted in other applications. Instead, usage of the 'ThreadJob' module is recommended in such scenarios

My script looks something like below.

**Note** the invocation of the web request does indeed fail with an HTTP 500, triggering, I assume the `catch` block and the `if`.

```
try {
    Invoke-WebRequest ...
}
catch {
   $exc = $_;
}

if ($null -ne $exc) {
    Writing-Warning "This failed when something blah.";
    throw $exc;
}
```

This is the gyst. The real script actually makes a few web requests, any of which could fail. I want to ensure they all get executed, so I catch and then store the exception, and then only at the end the script can throw and fail, and my hope is at least one of the problems makes it out into logging or somewhere in the portal or something.

The actual message looks like this. It smells like an Azure problem to me.

[image: Error output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran it again and it fixed itself. Thanks for wasting my time, Azure.

[image: Console output]